# Passing data from one function to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to edit data from a table .

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5crffhbd/)

the important part of codes are :

**Edit**

```
$scope.editUser = function(param){

        if(param == 'new' ){
            $scope.fName = '';
            $scope.lName = '';
            $scope.edit = true;
        }else{
            $scope.edit = false;
            $scope.fName = $scope.users[param-1].fName;
            $scope.lName = $scope.users[param-1].lName;
            //console.log($scope.users[param-1].lName);
        }

    };
```

**ng-click on Save button**

```
$scope.add = function(){
    $scope.users.push({
        fName:$scope.users.fName,
        lName:$scope.users.lName
    });
    $scope.users.fName = "";
    $scope.users.lName = "";
    console.log($scope.users.lName);
};
```

how can i pass data from `edit function` to `add function` for saving ?
many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (almost) the right ViewModel, and you don't need to pass anything between these functions - they are not calling each other.

You have `$scope.users` and you have `$scope.fName` and `$scope.lName`. That is fine - you just need to "remember" which user was being edited.

I would just slightly change this to:

```
$scope.users = [...]; // whatever you have
$scope.userBeingEditedCopy = null;
var userBeingEditedMaster = null;
```

Then, when "edit" is clicked, pass it the actual user object to be edited:

```
$scope.editUser = function(user){
   userBeingEditedMaster = user;
   $scope.userBeingEditedCopy = angular.copy(userBeingEditedMaster);
}
```

When you want to save changes, you already have all the data:

```
$scope.saveChanges = function(){
   angular.copy($scope.userBeingEditedCopy, userBeingEditedMaster);
   // optionally, remove the user from being edited
   userBeingEditedMaster = $scope.userBeingEditedCopy = null;
}
```

In the View it is easy to wire these up:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
   <button ng-click="editUser(user)">Edit</button>
   {{user.fName}} {{user.lName}}
</div>


<h3>Edit User:</h3>

<div>first name: <input ng-model="userBeingEditedCopy.fName"></div>
<div>last name: <input ng-model="userBeingEditedCopy.lName"></div>
<button ng-click="saveChanges()">Save Changes</button>
```

Comment: thank you, this helped me a lot , but how can i be good in this stuff ? i have no idea how to fix it

Comment: how to fix what? I don't understand

Comment: i mean i had no idea . your solution is great .
One more question : there is a button (Add new user) , should i save data in save changes function ?

Comment: Sure, just play with the logic of existing vs. new. You could introduce a flag, or just play off of `userBeingEditedMaster` being `null`.

Comment: are u there @New Dev ?

Comment: @Soheil, you understand that this is a Q&A site, not chat, right? :) Ask for clarification in a comment - I'll try to answer; or, if it's unrelated - ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

In your edit function call add function like this

```
$scope.add()
```

If you need to pass any parameters

```
$scope.add(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

call add function as `$scope.add(param1,param2,..);`

define add function as `$scope.add=function(param1,param2..){};`

But, I see all the variables in your code are scope variables , if you want to modify only those then you can directly use them in add function instead of passing them as parameters.